# Sender address rejected using Ansible mail

Tags: email, ansible

I get the following error when I try to send an email from an Ansible playbook using mail.

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'Jack.Jones@nsd.com': (504, '5.5.2 <root>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address')}
```

The playbook contains

```
- name: Send the processing resumed email
  mail:
    host: smtphost.nsd.com
    port: 25
    to: Jack.Jones@nsd.com
    subject: "Processing of {{ event_name }} events has been resumed"
    body: "Processing of {{ event_name }} events has been automatically resumed by the CICD pipeline."
```

I've tried all sorts of variations for the to: address and nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So the error message is a bit misleading the problem is actually caused by the absence of the **from:** field not the value in the **to:** field.

In the absence of the **from:** field a default value of **root** is used. As it does not have the @nsd.com extension on it and is thus malformed from the point of view of the email server.

After adding the **from:** field to the playbook it works properly.

```
- name: Send the processing resumed email
  mail:
    host: smtphost.nsd.com
    port: 25
    to: Jack.Jones@nsd.com
    from: CICD.Resume.Service@nsd.com
    subject: "Processing of {{ event_name }} events has been resumed"
    body: "Processing of {{ event_name }} events has been automatically resumed by the CICD pipeline."
```